# MJML - Centering a line of text with an icon

Tags: center, vertical-alignment, mjml

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to vertically center a line of text with an icon, which is supposed to look like this

[image]

My first attempt is by nesting inside of `mj-text`

```
<mj-section background-color="#fff" padding="45px 0">
    <mj-hero>
        <mj-text align="center">
          Find your next <span class="neon-red">Meetup</span> <img style="width: 12px" src="img/chevron--right.png" />
        </mj-text>
    </mj-hero>
</mj-section>
```

This doesn't vertically align texts and the icon
[image]

I've also tried making tables, but no improvements were made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that it was a simple css error.  I needed to vertically-align the image, that was all ‍♂️

```
<mj-section background-color="#fff" padding="45px 0">
    <mj-hero>
        <mj-text align="center">
          Find your next <span class="neon-red">Meetup</span> <img style="width: 12px; vertical-align: middle" src="img/chevron--right.png" />
        </mj-text>
    </mj-hero>
</mj-section>
```

Comment: This example also helped me: https://mjml.io/try-it-live/Hy7SOYfl4